# Derivative using first principle method

Tags: derivatives

How to find the derivative of $\frac{(x+1)}{\sqrt x}$ using first principle method?

I am able to solve the above using binomial theorem but i want to learn the method without binomial theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by *first principle*?

Comment: First principle method or delta method or ab initio method

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net he means by the definition of the derivative

Answer (score 1):

You can get away with it by observing that
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
Then you can do, for $x>0$,
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to0}
  \frac{\sqrt{x+h}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}}-\sqrt{x}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}{h}
&=\lim_{h\to0}\left(
  \frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}+
  \frac{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}{h}
\right) \\[6px]
&=\lim_{h\to0}\left(
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}+
\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+h}}{h\sqrt{x}\,\sqrt{x+h}}
\right)
\end{align}
and you can finish it up easily.

In other words, pretend you're ignoring that the derivative of the sum is the sum of the derivatives, but act with this important knowledge in the background.

Answer (score 1):

By definition;

$f'(x) =\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

$f(x)= \dfrac{x+1}{\sqrt x}$

$f(x+h) = \dfrac{x+h+1}{\sqrt{x+h}}$

$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to0}\dfrac{\frac{x+h+1}{\sqrt{x+h}}-\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}}}{h}$

$f'(x)= \lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt{x}(x+h+1)-\sqrt{x+h}(x+1)}{\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{x+h}\cdot h}$

$f'(x) =\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt{x}(x+h+1)-\sqrt{x+h}(x+1)}{\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{x+h}\cdot h}\times \dfrac{\sqrt{x}(x+h+1)+\sqrt{x+h}(x+1)}{\sqrt{x}(x+h+1)+\sqrt{x+h}(x+1)}$

$f'(x) =\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{x(x+h+1)^2-(x+h)(x+1)^2}{x\cdot h\cdot\sqrt{x+h}(x+h+1)+(x+h)\cdot h\cdot \sqrt{x}(x+1)}$

$f'(x) =\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{x(x+h+1)^2-x(x+1)^2}{x\cdot h\cdot\sqrt{x+h}(x+h+1)+(x+h)\cdot h\cdot \sqrt{x}(x+1)}-\dfrac{h(x+1)^2}{x\cdot h\cdot\sqrt{x+h}(x+h+1)+(x+h)\cdot h\cdot \sqrt{x}(x+1)}$

$f'(x) =\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{x(x+h+1)^2-x(x+1)^2}{x\cdot h\cdot\sqrt{x+h}(x+h+1)+(x+h)\cdot h\cdot \sqrt{x}(x+1)}-\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{x\cdot\sqrt{x+h}(x+h+1)+(x+h)\cdot  \sqrt{x}(x+1)}$

expand the numerator of the first term gives ;

$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{ x(x^2+2xh+2x+h^2+2h+1)-x(x^2+1+2x)}{x\cdot h\cdot\sqrt{x+h}(x+h+1)+(x+h)\cdot h\cdot \sqrt{x}(x+1)}-\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{x\cdot\sqrt{x+h}(x+h+1)+(x+h)\cdot  \sqrt{x}(x+1)}$

$f'(x) =\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{2x^2h+h^2x+2hx}{x\cdot h\cdot\sqrt{x+h}(x+h+1)+(x+h)\cdot h\cdot \sqrt{x}(x+1)}-\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{x\cdot\sqrt{x+h}(x+h+1)+(x+h)\cdot  \sqrt{x}(x+1)}$

$f'(x) =\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{2x^2+hx+2x}{x\cdot\sqrt{x+h}(x+h+1)+(x+h)\cdot  \sqrt{x}(x+1)}-\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{x\cdot\sqrt{x+h}(x+h+1)+(x+h)\cdot  \sqrt{x}(x+1)}$

applying the limit gives;

$f'(x)= \dfrac{2x(x+1)}{2x\sqrt{x}(x+1)}-\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{2x(x+1)\sqrt{x}}$

$f'(x)= \dfrac1{\sqrt x}-\dfrac{x}{2x\sqrt{x}}-\dfrac1{2x\sqrt{x}}$

$f'(x) =\dfrac{1}{\sqrt x}-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-\dfrac1{2x\sqrt{x}}$

$\therefore f'(x)=\frac 12 x^{-\frac12}-\frac12x^{-\frac 32}$

Comment: Edited to use `\dfrac` consistently throughout.

Comment: It would probably be simpler to note that $$\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x} = x^{1/2} + x^{-1/2},$$ then use the linearity of the limit to evaluate the derivatives of the two summands separately.  It would, at least, save a lot of notation.

Comment: @XanderHenderson yes it would have been , i think user egreg has posted the answer that way.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of a fraction $f(x)/g(x)$ is given by
$$\frac{f'(x) g(x) - f(x) g'(x)}{[g(x)]^2}.$$
Where, in your case, $f(x) = x+1$, $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$, $f'(x) =1$, $g'(x) = 1/(2\sqrt x)$.

Comment: I know quotient rule. But my requirement is use of first principle method i.e use of limits.